# Override Static Method for TestNg Class

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

Is there a way to add a screenshot in this Assert method? When my softAssert fails, I need it to take a screenshot here.

Method of Assert.class :

```
static public void fail(String message) {
    throw new AssertionError(message);
  }
```

As you can see, it is static so I cannot override it.

Answer (score 1):

One cannot override static methods, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223405).
Nonetheless, you can still call it from subclasses, but with a different method (different name or arguments).

```
class AssertWithScreenhot extends Assert {

  public void failWithScreenshot(String message) {
    takeScreenshot();  
    fail(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on your answer or just an example if possible if not it s fine

Comment: I've added an toy-example.